# Parse XML from Axios response, pushing to Vue data array

Tags: xml, vue.js, axios, xml2js

In my Vue app, I get an XML file with Axios and use `parseString` to parse XML as JSON. I then need to pass the `result` to Vue data (`this.events`). My `console.log` shows the parsed XML as JSON, but I cannot push to Vue data inside this function.

```
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;

axios.get(`http://url.to/events.xml`)
  .then(response => {
    parseString(response.data, function (err, result) {
      console.log(result); // returns a json array
      this.events = result // nothing happens
    });        
  })
}
```

How do I store my JSON array to `this.data` in Vue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try not to use `this` inside `parseString`, maybe it's a scope issue, which means `this` isn't referring to the vue data object.

Try this:

```
axios.get('http://url.to/events.xml')
  .then(response => {
    var self = this; 
    parseString(response.data, function (err, result) {
      self.events = result
    });        
  })
}
```

Comment: That helped, I'm able to pass the data now. Thanks!

Comment: You could make use of an ES6 arrow function to maintain the execution context and still use this :)

Answer (score 7):

[This answer](/a/48788275/10248678) is correct. However, I would just use arrow functions everywhere so the `this` is always the VUE class component. Also, I would check for parsing errors.

```
axios.get('http://url.to/events.xml')
  .then(response => {
    parseString(response.data, (err, result) => {
      if(err) {
       //Do something
      } else {
       this.events = result
     }
    });        
  })
}
```