# Gridsome returning xml api - graphql layer

Tags: api, vue.js, graphql, axios, gridsome

Hello I am having difficulty returning an api end point in Gridsome via the Gridsome documented way. I think it is because what is returned is xml insead of pure json.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how to get this data into the graphql layer in Gridsome. This is the documented way to return the data this works for pure json i.e. https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts but not for http://balfourmanson.master.d8digital.com/umbraco/api/NewsAndEventsApi/getall

```
const axios = require('axios')
module.exports = function (api) {
api.loadSource(async actions => {
const collection = actions.addCollection('News')
const {
  data
} = await 
axios.get('http://balfourmanson.master.d8digital.com/umbraco/api/NewsAndEventsApi/getall')
for (const item of data) {
  collection.addNode({
    id: item.id,
    title: item.title,
    content: item.content
  })
}
})
 }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you know the balfourmanson API offers a JSON response, you may need to pass a header parameter in your axios request in order to return the data in JSON format.

Comment: ^ then the above code should work

Comment: Thanks for getting back, I tried this and it doesnt seem to make a difference. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

have a look into this post:
[Parse XML from Axios response, pushing to Vue data array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48788185/parse-xml-from-axios-response-pushing-to-vue-data-array)

This should do the trick. Afterwards you can map your fields.
If you have problems come back here.

Comment: Thank - I will try this and let you know - Im a slow worker so might be a while. Thanks.

Comment: thanks for your feedback here - turns out it was a different problem or me just being dumb. the errors I was getting were due to me misunderstanding things. I was trying to call items that didnt exist in the collection bit and not having unique ids.

Comment: You're welcome and no worries.
I see. Good if you're making progress.